# Convert Flat list to Relational List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a "flat" array of data in struct Foo which has members parent and child:

```
struct Foo { string parent, string child }
```

They might have data like so:

```
"parent1", "child1"
"parent1", "child2"
"parent2", "child3"
"parent2", "child4"
```

I want to coerce them to a "relational" struct:

```
struct Bar { string parent, string[] children }
```

and have the filled like so:

```
"parent1"
    "child1"
    "child2"
"parent2"
    "child3"
    "child4"
```

I can do it via loops just fine, but looking to improve my linq skills... I'm sure there must be a way?  Thanks (4.5 framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
array.GroupBy(f => f.parent)
    .Select(g => new Bar { parent = g.Key, children = g.Select(f => f.child).ToArray() })
    .ToArray();
```